# PHP: merge elements of an array based on specific key & value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've tried about 20 different ideas for this and I think I've gone in so many circles I can't remember where I started. I'm sure this is a simple one too.

I have an array;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 15
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime] => 183.75
            [type] => 0

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 15
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime] => 64.50
            [type] => 1            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 23
            [first_name] => Person2
            [surname] => Person2
            [totaltime] => 2.00
            [type] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 51
            [first_name] => Person3 
            [surname] => Person3
            [totaltime] => 119.25
            [type] => 0            
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 59
            [first_name] => Person4
            [surname] => Person4
            [totaltime] => 170.75
            [type] => 0
        )
)
```

I need to merge the elements where the `employee` number is the same and add the `totaltime` elements to new keys based on the `type`. This is what I mean.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 15
            [first_name] => Person1
            [surname] => Person1
            [totaltime_type_0] => 183.75
            [totaltime_type_1] => 64.50

        )       

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 23
            [first_name] => Person2
            [surname] => Person2
            [totaltime_type_0] => 2.00
            [totaltime_type_1] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 51
            [first_name] => Person3 
            [surname] => Person3
            [totaltime_type_0] => 119.25
            [totaltime_type_1] => 0            
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [employee] => 59
            [first_name] => Person4
            [surname] => Person4
            [totaltime_type_0] => 170.75
            [totaltime_type_1] => 0
        )
)
```

I could do this at the query level but the SQL to create the original array is so complex I'd rather only maintain the one version of it.

Any suggestions on the best approach would really help me get back on track with this. And will be REALLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$res      = array();
foreach($your_array as $val){
   $res[$val['employee']]['employee']         = $val['employee'];
   $res[$val['employee']]['first_name']       = $val['first_name'];
   $res[$val['employee']]['surname']          = $val['surname'];
   if($val['type'] == 0){
      if(array_key_exists("totaltime_type_0",$res[$val['employee']])){
         $res[$val['employee']]['totaltime_type_0'] += $val['totaltime'];
      }
      else{
         $res[$val['employee']]['totaltime_type_0'] = $val['totaltime'];
      }
   }
   if($val['type'] == 1){
      if(array_key_exists("totaltime_type_1",$res[$val['employee']])){
         $res[$val['employee']]['totaltime_type_1'] += $val['totaltime'];
      }
      else{
         $res[$val['employee']]['totaltime_type_1'] = $val['totaltime'];
      }
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($res));
```

Comment: That was a super fast answer and is working perfectly! Thank you. I owe you one ;-)